# Convert C to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, converters

Is there a way to convert my C code to objective C code, instead of manually writing the code into objective C? I figure this would be easier to do than most other languages since Objective C is a superset of C.

Comment: Personally, I would definitively enjoy something to convert water into beer...

Comment: C already _IS_ Objective-C (unless you are using any of Objective-C's reserved words as variable names). Objective-C without any classes.

Comment: Use alchemy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemy

Comment: If you're running *nix, this command should be able to convert any file containing valid C code to a file containing valid Objective-C code: `cat input.c > output.m`

Comment: There!!  You're done!

Comment: Plain old C can be compiled (without even changing the file type) and made a part of an Objective-C app.  But understand that the UI and system interfaces must be written in Objective-C (or in some rather arcane C-language equivalents), so you can't really do without some Objective-C.

Comment: @Frxstrem This doesn't work for me; I get the error: `Error: 'sarcastic_arse.so' not found on $PATH, unable to convert.`

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of C. This means that all code valid in C is also valid in Objective-C. A straight copy and past will `a)` probably not work because implementation of functions is different in Objective-C `b)` not be wise. Objective-C was made for a reason. It works great for its intended purpose. For this reason, writing C code as a substitute for Objective-C is not a good idea.

Comment: The question is obviously about converting to a strict superset of Objective C that works with the NS nonsense, and with all the horrible and pointless syntax.  This is a non-answer, and is instead an opinion piece without any backup provided for the claims.  Especially the "works great" and "not a good idea" purely subjective claims.  `The comment I'm leaving is also written in the exact same manner so as to make painfully clear--to those who have joined the religion--what it looks like to read baseless, subjective opinions that don't answer the question.`